# How can I access/modify headers of request/reponses in a Delphi 2010 DataSnap Server

Tags: delphi, http, delphi-2010, webdav, datasnap

I'm in the process of building a DataSnap Server that functions as WebDAV server and I'm trying to read the request headers when using a DSHTTPService and then modify the response headers.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I've notice the Trace TDSRequest and TDSResponse are ancestors of TDSRequestIndy and TDSResponseIndy and those components have access to the headers but am not entirely sure how to get from a TDSRequest to TDSRequestIndy.

Also I didn't think that the Trace would be the cleanest way to access the request and response, but it's the only way I've found so far.

The reason for trying to do this with DataSnap and not just straight Indy is that I'm looking to use DataSnap for other remote methods.

Comment: Good question, also it could be interesting to get access to cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider using TidHTTPServer and create an indy server that has many events and methods, rather than starting from DSHTTPService, including OnBeforeBind, OnAfterBind, OnHeadersAvailable... in which you have access to headers

Comment: Thanks for the reply after such a long time with no answer.

Unfortunately, I would prefer to only use 1 port in the server and would like to combine the DataSnap and WebDAV parts of the server.  I have since found that I can reimplement the TDSHTTPServerIndy which is normally private, which then gives me access to the full request and response objects.